# Can I add a list<string> in a database? code first Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, code-first

I created a database in VS and I wanted to add a list of images in a class, that gave me warning and I decided to add a list of strings instead (with the path). The database was created, but there was no location created in the database.

What is the best way to go here?

```
 public class HuisModel
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private List<string> _photos;

        [Key]
        public int Id { get => _id; set => _id = value; }
        public string Naam { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
        public List<string> photos { get => _photos; set => _photos = value; }

        public HuisModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*there was no location created in the database*"? No Table was created? Can you describe what you would expect table(s) would look like if you created them manually? Particularly for `photos`, are you expecting a one-to-many table? Something else?

Comment: @Crowcoder I was wondering if you could put a list string in a colum from a table or do you have to create a seperate table for every list I want to use?

Comment: You can't put a list of strings in a column and maintain the fact that it is a List<string>. You would have to serialize it, like comma separated or something but that is bad design. If you are going to use a relational database then you should have a row in another table for each photo with a foreign key to the HuisModel's Id.

Comment: You may want other properties in the future. Creating a table instead of hacking your own custom storage semantics is better for numerous reasons. Also, it's perfectly possible to save an image in a database.

Comment: If you wanted to put a list of strings in a database field...use json. @Crowcoder eluded to this by serializing it.